# How to send data from android to server after 3-5 sec?

Tags: android

I want to know If I send HttpClient request from android repeatedly after 5 sec using async task would it create any problem. If it creates any problem then how should I send data to my server in a repeated manner?

Comment: Well it will consume the battery

Comment: Please send me proper solution for that.

Comment: That solution I was talking about. Async Task with timer task. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get **NetworkOnMainThreadException** when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

Try using the following code inside your AsyncTask class or a separate thread and execute:

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor;

scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

private void startThreadOnce() {
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        // Send data here.
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 0=initial delay, 5=interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS=time in seconds
}
```

Also look at these answers:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html
[Periodically send data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031516/periodically-send-data-to-server)